# Why does find. -maxdepth 1 with the -a option/flag not return any results on Linux?

Tags: linux, find

I would like to find all png AND jpg files and used the following command and no results are returned however if I replace `-a` with `-o` it shows me the list of files. Why is that?

```
`find . -maxdepth 1 \( -iname \*\.png -a -iname \*\.jpg \)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A logic error. What you're telling `find` is:

> find, in this folder, all files that are (PNG and JPG)

But, of course, there are no files that are *both* at the same time, which is why the `-o` works:

> find, in this folder, all files that are (PNG or JPG)

When constructing these queries just imagine `find` passing each file to the test. Then apply [boolean logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_logic). So for example:

- It finds a .txt file. It's not a PNG (false), and not a JPG (false), so *false && false* equals false
- It finds is a .png file. It's a PNG (true), and not a JPG (false), so *true && false* equals false
- It finds is a .jpg file. It's not a PNG (false), and it's a JPG (true), so *false && true* equals false
- If you use the `-o` switch, and it finds a .png file, then it's a PNG (true) and it's not a JPG (false), so *true || false* equals true.

Comment: Thanks slhck. How would I construct it correctly so that it would find files that are only PNG and JPG? I have a thousand files that are either text files, documents of sorts, images (PNG, JPG), etc.

Comment: With `-o` instead of `-a`, like I said. If you don't get any results, then you're searching in the wrong directory.

Comment: So does it treat each query independently i.e. `-iname \*\.png` is looked at as 1 query followed by the second query of `-iname \*\.jpg`?

Comment: Yes. `find` will evaluate both "queries" to whether they're true or false, and then combine the result of both with the logic test (and/or). If  the result is `true`, the file is found. As I wrote in my example, if the first test is `true` ("It's a PNG!") and the second is `false` ("It's not a JPG!"), this evaluates to `true` when combined with a logical `or`.

Answer (score 2):

-a is a logical AND meaning that the file name must end in both .PNG and .JPG to be true.

-o is a logical inclusive OR meaning the file name must end in .PNG or .JPG (or both) to be true.

Comment: Thanks parkydr. What would it be for both PNG and JPG?

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey `-o` instead of `-a`, as I wrote in my answer as well.